# converting RegEx into my Java function

Tags: java, regex

I'm having problems with Java RegEx. That's my regex statement `"\"730\"\s+{([^}]+)}"` and it works on an regex checking website, but I have trouble getting it to work in Java. That's my current code.

```
    String patternString = '\"730\"\s+{([^}]+)}';
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(vdfContentsString);
    boolean matches = matcher.matches();
```

Thanks for advice.

It says "Illegal escape character in character literal".

Comment: you are definitely getting compile time error?

Comment: @Braj It says "Illegal escape character in character literal".

Comment: @Braj that's the part I want to find:      "730"
     {
      "installdir"  "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\Counter-Strike Global Offensive"
      "HasAllLocalContent"  "1"
      "UpToDate"  "1"
     }

Comment: Now it says "Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 7
"730"\s+{([^}]+)}"

Comment: what is the value of `vdfContentsString`?

Comment: This is it http://pastebin.com/wsDC2sBN

Comment: have a look at my post.

Answer (score 1):

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition

Escape `{` and `}` as well because in [Java Regex Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) it has special meaning.

```
String patternString = "\"730\"\\s+\\{([^\\}]+)\\}";
```

---

#### EDIT

[String#matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method looks for whole string if you are looking for sub-string of a long string then use [Matcher#find()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) method and get the result from the groups that is captured by enclosing the pattern inside parenthisis `(...)`.

sample code:

```
String patternString = "(\"730\"\\s+\\{([^\\}]+)\\})";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(vdfContentsString);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Now there are no matches when in theory it should find one

Comment: have a look at the sample code. Is this what are you doing?

Comment: that's exactly what I do

Comment: It works with that one, but when I use the real text file it doesn't anymore

Comment: The problem is with `String.matches()` that matches whole string not just a part of it. have a look at the update

Comment: +1, I often get thrown off for a second in Java and Ruby regex—other flavors don't require escaping of the `{}` :)

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes (`'`) declare characters, double quotes (`"`) declare strings, that's why you get the syntax error `Illegal escape character in character literal`. Second, regex itself syntactically uses the backslash, as in `\s` for whitespace. Maybe confusing might be the fact that Java also uses `\` for character escaping. That's why you need *two* backslashes (`\\s` in Java will become `\s` for the resulting regular expression).

Then you need to take care of special characters in regular expressions: `{` and `}` are quantifiers ("repeat n times"), if you want them literally, escape them (`\\{` and `\\}`)

So if you want to match a string like `"730"  {whatever}`, use this regular expression:

```
 "730"\s+\{([^}]+)\}
```

or in Java:

```
 String patternString = "\"730\"\\s+\\{([^}]+)\\}";
```

Example:

```
    String str = "\"730\" { \"installdir\" \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\" \"HasAllLocalContent\" \"1\" \"UpToDate\" \"1\" }";
    String patternString = "\"730\"\\s+\\{([^}]+)\\}";
    System.out.println(str.matches(patternString)); // true
```

Comment: @user3347446 If you're reading from a text file, trim the string (`String line = line.trim();`) after reading a line to remove line breaks *or* add `(?s).*` or `[\r\n]*` to the regular expression above in order to match line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

`{`, `}` are `Metacharacters` (See [HERE](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/regular-expression/metacharacter-list.php) for metacharacters) and need to be escaped with `\\`, hence, `\\{ .. \\}`.

`\` is an **escape character**, while `\s, \w, \d etc` (See [HERE](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#regex_metacharacters) for a list) are `metacharacters`, therefore, as mentioned above, these need to be escaped as well, hence, `\\s+`

instead of `[^\\}]`, i would suggest `(.+?)}`

This is working:

```
String patternString = '\\\"730\\\"\\s+\\{(.+?)\\}';
```

The above is the required `Java string` which gets parsed into the following `regular expression: \"730\"\s+\{(.+?)\}`, and then it can be used to match the input string. ***Tadan!***
two levels of parsing!

Comment: It doesn't find matches, though, when in theory it should.

Comment: u're welcome! check this: http://fiddle.re/ew005 .. click `Java` and see how the regex is being linked to the java string and subsequently matched